# Ionic React - Prefill form element

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I'm struggling to get prefill my form elements (hundreds of them using the a textarea element) with values coming from an API (i.e. my DB).

On the code below, defaultValue doesn't work (and I don't thin it's supposed to work like that) and when I set {item.contact_note} to the value={} attribute, my setState doesn't work (i.e. everytime I type a letter the textarea is not updated)...

I've tried to set a state array for all my notes within the map loop to create one state note for each note but doesn't work (depth issue).

Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import {IonContent,  IonPage,IonItem,IonButton,IonLabel,IonTextarea} from '@ionic/react';

type State = {
  items: Array<any>,
  note:string
}
class Test extends React.Component<{},State> { 
  constructor(props:any) {  
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: Array<any>(), 
      note: ''
    }  
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event : any) {
    const target = event.target;
    this.setState({note:target.value});
  }
  saveNote(uid_contact: string){
    console.log(this.state.note);
    //Save note -- removed coded for readability
  }
  render(){  
    return ( 
        <IonPage>      
            <IonContent>  
                  {this.state.items.map((item,key) => {
                      return (
                        <>
                          <IonItem>
                              <IonLabel position="stacked">Add a note : </IonLabel>
                              <IonTextarea defaultValue={item.contact_note} value={this.state.note} onIonChange={this.handleChange}></IonTextarea>
                          </IonItem>

                          <IonButton color="primary" expand="block" onClick={() => this.saveNote(item.uid_user)}>Save note</IonButton> 
                        </>    
                      )
                  })}
            </IonContent>  
        </IonPage>
    );
  }
};

export default Test;
```

Probably a newbie issue...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure this is exactly what you're after, but try replacing 'defaultValue' with 'placeholder'

Comment: This is how I've set out an auto filled form before - 

<IonTextarea className={"clsName"} value={val} placeholder={"Placeholder text"}
                         onIonChange={(e) => {
                             setVariable((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
                         }}/>

Comment: Thanks @JamesBrightman but it doesn't work. OnIonChange doesn't change the {val}, hence when you type the textarea doesn't show the output.